# Cómo reanudar un setInterval

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo reanudar un interval que anteriormente fue detenido, sin ser necesario que empiece desde el número donde quedó pero si que sea el interval alojado en la variable *interval*

```js
let counter = 0;

let interval = setInterval(function() {

counter = counter + 1;

console.log(counter);

}, 1000);


function stop() {

clearInterval(interval);

}

function ready() {

// ...

}
```

```html
<button onclick="stop()">Detener</button>
<button onclick="ready()">Reanudar</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Si lo que deseas es pausar, creo que no deberias usar clearInterval, pues esta accion cancela el interval.

Para esto creo que teniendo un booleano, podrias validar si debe o no parar, ya podrias usar el clearInterval, cuando desees dar por terminado el interval.

```js
let counter = 0;
let isPause = false;

let interval = setInterval(function() {

if(!isPause){
  counter = counter + 1;
  console.log(counter);
}

}, 1000);


function stop() {

isPause = true;

}

function ready() {

isPause = false;

}
```

```html
<button onclick="stop()">Detener</button>
<button onclick="ready()">Reanudar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Si reasignas el interval puedes seguir usando la misma variable, así:

```js
let counter = 0;

let interval;

function start() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {

    counter = counter + 1;

    console.log(counter);

  }, 1000);
}


function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);

}

function ready() {
  start();
  // ...

}

start();
```

```html
<button onclick="stop()">Detener</button>
<button onclick="ready()">Reanudar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

setInterval requiere que le pases el nombre de la función así que yo lo resolvería así:

```
let counter = 0;

let FunctionName = function() {

counter = counter + 1;

console.log(counter);

};
let interval = setInterval(FunctionName, 1000);


function stop() {

clearInterval(interval);

}

function ready() {

// Aquí le pasas el nombre de la función
interval = setInterval(FunctionName, 1000);

}
<button onclick="stop()">Detener</button>
<button onclick="ready()">Reanudar</button>
```